# Drupal 6 responsive Zen sub theme?

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, drupal-zen

I am having zero luck searching for work or information regarding a version 6 responsive zen sub theme. Rather than recreate the wheel I thought I would inquire here for any leads. This is also my first time posting to stack so apologies in advance if this question is better asked elsewhere.

I am also wondering if the v6 Zen base kit isn't a good candidate for responsive design due to the already heavy use of stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Zen base theme has been (mostly?) made responsive.

To build a responsive sub-theme with Zen, you'll need [Zen Grids](http://zengrids.com/)

Edit: Just noticed you were asking about D6, so YMMV. If you're building a responsive site it's likely a *much* better idea to just BTB and upgrade to D7.